# iPhone: How to detect if iTunes is playing?

Tags: iphone, audio, itunes

I noticed that some apps programmatically mute itunes (if its running) at launching. How is this achieved? I have a game with background music and would like to either stop itunes or get at least a message that itunes is playing so that I can stop the game's background music.

thx,
marc.

Answer (score 8):

**You don't need to. With Audio Session you can decide how the audio should behave.**

From the [**Audio Session Programming Guide**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> With the audio session interface, you
>   specify aspects of your application’s
>   audio behavior and configure it to
>   live harmoniously within the iPhone
>   audio environment. You start by asking
>   yourself questions such as these:
>
> - Do you want your audio to be silenced by the Ring/Silent switch?
>     The answer is probably “yes” if audio
>     is not essential to using your
>     application successfully. (Users will
>     appreciate being able to run your game
>     in a meeting with no one the wiser.)
> - Do you want iPod audio to continue playing when your audio
>     starts? This could be appropriate for
>     a virtual piano, letting users play
>     along to songs in their libraries.
>     You’d want iPod audio to stop,
>     however, for a streaming radio
>     application.

**You probably want this:**

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty (
    kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
    sizeof (sessionCategory),
    &sessionCategory
);
```

**For more behaviour types, check the [Audio Session Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html), or read the entire [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).**

Answer (score 0):

I had the opposite problem.  My app plays a short video with no sound after launch.  This caused the iTunes music playing in the background to mute.

In order to keep the music playing, I add this in the applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
NSError* error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: &error];    
    if (error) NSLog(@"Unable to configure Audio");
```